# Google Chrome Extremely Slow or Cannot Connect Sometimes Crashes My Wifi

Tags: networking, google-chrome, installation, browser

I recently reset my laptop so that I could give it to my mother as she needed a new one. However, since resetting it, it has been acting very strangely. Specifically, Google Chrome does not work correctly.

The first strange issue is that the Google Chrome web based installer takes forever (upwards of 3 plus minutes) during the "Connecting to Internet" Phase.

Now here is where it gets really strange. Upon opening the browser, it loads up the Google search home page as normal, but if I try to navigate to a URL or search anything it will say "Connecting..." at the bottom left side of the browser and just sit there for minutes at a time. At this point one of two things will happen:

1. The site will load
2. The request will time out

Either way occasionally my home's entire wifi will go down and reset itself. This is absolutely mind-bending, but I tested this multiple times and it cannot be a coincidence that the WI-Fi just happens to reset it self in a way that it has never done before right after Chrome tries to make a connection from that PC. I say Wi-Fi because I have not tested to see if wired connections still work. But at any rate, all of my home connections disappear from the Wi-Fi tab for about five minutes.

Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox work perfectly, However.

A clue to this mystery is that every page that I try to load (even Google.com) has a small "i" icon next to the url that when clicked says "Your connection to this site is not secure You should not enter any sensitive information on this site (for example, passwords or credit cards), because it could be stolen by attackers. Learn more". If a site is successfully connected to then the "i" will turn into a lock and say that the connection is secure.

I believe that something is happening with Chrome in regards to security settings on my computer or within the browser. But I think it is so strange that it brings down my entire internet sometimes. Also, I don't know why the other browsers work fine.

Also, during my first reset of the computer when I tried to install Mozilla Firefox. The Windows program that asks you if you would like to run the file alerted me that it could not connect to the internet to check if the file was safe or not. I think this may be connected to my issue, but I have not been able to replicate.

Again this is a fresh computer that I completely reset using windows recovery. I created a new Microsoft.com account for my mom, and I have not installed any third-party programs.

I have tried:

1. Re-Installing Google Chrome multiple times
2. Resetting the entire computer and fresh installing Windows twice
3. Clearing Cache and Cookies
4. Turning off Auto-Detect Proxy
5. Turning off my Firewall while i try to make a request.
6. I checked to make sure Chrome was in my firewalls whitelist.
7. I reset some settings using IP config, but cannot find the tutorial that explained it at the moment, so cannot provide more details about this one.
8. Checking that my time was correct.

I'm using Windows 10, am installing the latest version of Chrome from their website, do not have a proxy, and my other computers do not have any issues with Chrome.

Not sure what to do at this point. I can't exactly give this computer away in its current state. Any thoughts on this matter? What else should I try?

Thanks for taking a look!